# Find similar records based on race_id and animal_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have a model called `Adoption`:

```
class Adoption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :animal
  belongs_to :race

  searchkick language: 'french'

  def search_data
    {
      # name: name,
      # description: description,
      race_id: race_id,
      animal_id: animal_id
    }
  end
end
```

So, now I want to find similar adoptions. I've created two adoption records with same data. In rails console, I do these commands: `Adoption.reindex`, then: `adoption = Adoption.find(1)`, and finally: `similars = adoption.similar(fields: %w[race_id^5 animal_id], limit: 3).records`. And it doesn't find any similar adoptions. But if I uncomment `name` in a `search_data` method, reindex and add `name` to the array of fields, it finds the adoption. So, what is wrong with my code? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try this similars = adoption.similar(fields: [:race_id, :animal_id], limit: 3).records

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
similars = adoption.similar(fields: [:race_id, :animal_id], limit: 3).records
```